# Configure SQuirrel SQL Client to work for DB2/AS400

Tags: sql, jdbc, db2, squirrel-sql

I use the ancient System i Navigator (french) to get to query a DB2 (AS/400) database.

I liked to update the client and use a more fresh (and English) sql client for that database.

So, I installed the **SQuirrel SQL client** (3.5.0, the latest at day).

After the installation and launching, I discovered that the "IBM DB2 App Driver" is not "checked".
The message when I click on it says:

> "Could not find class COM.ibm.db2.jdbc.app.DB2Driver in neither the
>   Java class path nor the Extra class path of the IBM DB2 App Driver
>   driver definition: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   COM.ibm.db2.jdbc.app.DB2Driver"

As I understood I need to copy a (universal?) JDBC driver in the SQuirrel "\lib" folder. How to get it?

I don't have any "classpath" defined in the environmental variables (I am on Windows 7 x64). 
I am not a Java developer, so I am not sure if I need or not to configure that classpath to make work that sql client.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

if it's an AS400, then you should use JTOpen libraries to connect.

http://jt400.sourceforge.net/

JT400 has the JARS you need to use.   Note, the class name mentioned above is not the same as what is expected on the AS400....

I remember it being something like this....

`com.ibm.as400.access.AS400JDBCDriver...` you'll want to double check

if you start `squirrel-sql` on the commandline you can add this

```
set CLASSPATH=%CLASSPATH%;c:/jt400.jar
```

Comment: you are a genius! I just added the jt400.jar in the "lib" folder of the SQuirrel SQL client.

Comment: I also recommend considering connection settings mentioned in http://stackoverflow.com/a/20559422/638798

Answer (score 0):

If want a really quick and easy "command-line" JDBC client, you can use the one included in the JTOpen.  I use it all the time so I don't have to open yet another window.

Here is an example.

```
~> java -cp jt400.jar com.ibm.as400.access.jdbcClient.Main jdbc:as400:AS400 SYSTEM USERID PASSWORD  
>select * from sysibm.sysdummy1
IBMREQD
Y
```